# Accessing properties of enclosing class

Tags: singleton, kotlin

How do I access the properties of an enclosing class? I am working with singletons in Kotlin.

```
private object IndeterminateAnimationListener : Animation.AnimationListener {
    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {}

    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
        // How do I access the properties of the enclosing
        // from here? 
    }

    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {}
}
```

PS: I can use `inner` classes, how do I do the same with singletons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A singleton can not be inner, because there is only one instance of it, and instances of inner classes keep references to instances of outer (enclosing) classes. Therefore, singleton objects can not hold references to enclosing classes, and can not access their properties.

As a workaround, use anonymous objects, which are not singletons:

```
class A(val foo: Int) {

    val listener = object : AnimationListenerAdapter { 
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
            println(foo) // access to outer
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use AnimationListenerAdapter if you don't need to override all the methods.